# How to add class to <li> located within a .html() variable?

Tags: jquery, append

I have a variable from where I save the HTML of a certain div:

```
var menu = $(".menu").html();
```

The saved html() = `var menu` looks as followed:

```
<li>
    <a href="#">item 1</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">item 2</a>
</li>
```

The two `<li>`'s are then copied over to another div

```
otherDiv.append(menu);
```

**The issue:** I want to add a class to each of the `<li>`'s contained in the .html() before I append them to `otherDiv`. The original `<li>`'s can't be touched and needs to remain in original state.

Comment: Why not use `children()` if you want to add classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach:

```
var menu = $('.menu')
    // cloning the found element(s), preserving event-handlers:
    .clone(true, true)
    // finding the descendant <li> elements:
    .find('li')
    // adding the 'newClass' class-name to those found <li> elements:
    .addClass('newClass')
    // returning to the original selection ('.menu'):
    .end()
    // retrieving the innerHTML:
    .html();
```

```js
var menu = $('.menu').clone(true, true).find('li').addClass('newClass').end().html();

$('#otherElement').html(menu);
```

```css
li a {
  color: #f00;
}
li.newClass a {
  color: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">item 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ol id="otherElement"></ol>
```

References:

- [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).
- [`end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery's [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/):

```
var menu = $(".menu").clone().html();
```

It will create a deep copy, and then you can add the class to each of the contained `<li>`. That way you won't alter the original elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing [.append( function )](http://api.jquery.com/append/#append-function) , [jQuery.parseHTML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/)

```js
var menu = $(".menu").html(), name = "other-menu";
$("#otherDiv").append(function() {
  return $.parseHTML(menu).map(function(html) {
    html.className = name;
    return html.outerHTML
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul class="menu">
<li>
    <a href="#">item 1</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">item 2</a>
</li>
</ul>
<ul id="otherDiv">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach without `.clone()` could be

```
var menu = $(".menu").html();
otherDiv.append(menu).find("li").addClass("test");
```

The original `li` elements remain untouched. I don't see the difference adding the *class* after the elements are appended though.